# Hinting GPU to kick to full speed from idle frequency

Tags: qt, opengl

In my OpenGL CAD application, the GPU is idle most of the time with sporadic frame refresh. I need GPU to run at active frequency instantly when zooming and panning of the scene happens.

Here is my problem - it takes approximately 100 ms for the on my system GPU to sense activity and kick from 125 mhz idle frequency to active frequency of 900 mhz  - So user of my application will be feeling 15 fps for 100 ms, and then follow by smooth 130 fps when the GPU gets to normal frequency.

My question - is there a standard OpenGL method to hint to the 'GPU' to wake up from idle speed, before the first new frame is rendered after a period of inactivity? I would prefer the GPU wake up from this hint rather than workload sensing (due to the lag).

Comment: Those are going to be horrific 100 milliseconds of CAD... Now seriously, maybe the problem is with your system power plan...

Comment: idk if you want it burning on full all the time anyway.  Some of these GPUs can get very noisy (my 7970 sounds like a wind tunnel when it's under stress).

Comment: @ddriver: The only problem is with the idea that it's ok to disable power saving and cut battery life by a factor of 3.  OP very much has the right idea -- use that extra power when needed, conserve when idle.

Comment: @BenVoigt - Having the GPU running at full clock will drain the battery anyway. The idea here is that without powersaving mode, clocks will likely be ramped up faster. GPU driver and firmware makers know their biz, if the GPU is idling it will clock down for a reason. But in power saving mode it will likely ramp up slower. Also, there is always the possibility to insert some dummy workload to prevent the GPU from clocking all the way down. Also it is possible the OP is not running on batteries by still uses something less than high performance setting.

Comment: Hi all, thank you for taking time to discuss this matter. GPU idling is a good thing. I don't want my app to kicking up the fan speed for a static screen . 
Normal realtime games would be continously rendering scenes and

Comment: that keeps the GPU active.  In a CAD environment, the scene is static for bulk of the time and the GPU will idle eventually.

Currently, I am doing a periodic 250 ms refresh on my static scene to keep the GPU active.. This is not an ideal solution. If only I can 'hint' the GPU to wake up before the next frame is rendered, then I won't get the 100 ms of jerky motion , while letting the GPU idle when not needed.

Comment: I do not know the architecture of your app but there is also another possibility: Are you copying any data to/from GPU just before the lag? It may be memory bandwidth related if you are updating VBO's ...

Answer (score 1):

I think that this "hint" does not exists, even on an extension, and it will never exists because the GPU needs time to "wake up", it is not only a matter of workload detection latency. Unless you can predict in advance the need of "waking up" the GPU you won't be able to hide the latency of a power status switch in that way.

However, there are multiple solutions/workarounds:

- Improve your app performance. If the workload is low even a low power mode will be enough.
- Decrease program workload when the GPU has been idle for a long period of time. Sometimes you can control de quality of the output, decreasing it for a few frames. This includes: use a lower resolution, deactivate anti-aliasing, use low-poly models, use simpler shaders...
- Use a different GPU. The power mode switch time is hardware dependent, each GPU will have different characteristics.
- Keep the GPU on the high power state. If the program redraws constantly, even when there aren't any changes, the GPU will be forced to run on the high power state. Of course, this is not energy efficient. Some drivers (at least Nvidia) can be configured by the user to avoid low-power modes (so you won't need to redraw all time).

Answer (score 0):

Not direct answer to your question but a silly suggestion instead (Handle as such)

**Why do you need 130 fps for CAD?**

My **CAD**'s have constant frame rate ~30 fps with use of double-buffering so if scene is not changed the old buffer is used instead of full render. There is no visible performance hit on sudden moves or zooms.

If you are redrawing after each zoom pan increment then that is not a good way (especially on slower computers) better is have one `bool _redraw` that is set on any change in view or **CAD** data and redraw/reset in timer if `_redraw` set. This time app will idle most of inactive time and when start to do stuff will still be fast enough. There is no problem if you miss few first frames if the App do the stuff smoothly.

Comment: I agree. Beyond 60 pcs, you can't really tell the difference... I just happen make it run at that framerate on a desktop with onboard GPU.  The app is designed to be ported to tablets. So I need to factor in GPU with 1/10th the power of desktop GPU.

I am trying to achieve framerate fluditiy without keeping the GPU at active frequency all the time.  The idle-to-active frequency lag is bothering me. It doesn't full 'fluid' . :(